# Error with Ajax Extensions for asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to get AJAX extensions working on an existing Web Forms Application.

I've added the AjaxControlToolkit using Nuget.  As a test I setup a page with a button and added a button confirmation extension.

I'm getting this error:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference

On the following line in the dynamically created Javascript:

```
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ConfirmButtonBehavior, {"ConfirmText":"Are ya totally sure?","id":"MainContent_Button1_ConfirmButtonExtender"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_Button1"));
```

I'm guessing that one of the libraries is the wrong version, but don't know how to go about figuring this out.  I've tried to update packages using Nuget.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager in page?

Comment: Yes.  I have a script manager on the Master Page.

Comment: Then try to register the AjaxToolkit with `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` in your page

Comment: PiLHA - That did the trick.  Thanks!!!! You've saved me some serious headache.  I removed the regular script manager from the master page and added ToolScriptManager and it's working great.  Put in an answer and I'll mark yours as correct.  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to register the `AjaxToolkit` with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: This needs to replace the ScriptManager (possibly in your MasterPage if you are using them).

Answer (score 6):

Many of the tutorials for the Ajax Control Toolkit tell you to use the "ScriptManager" from the Ajax Extensions tab.  With the latest versions (4.5) you need to use the "ToolkitScriptManager" from the toolkit.